# Use Laravel internals in another php website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an interesting question regarding Laravel.

I am building a control panel with certain functionality with Laravel 5.
This control panel will work standalone in a subdirectory of any another PHP website.

Here is how the folders tree looks like:

> /index.php
>   /(other php files from the main project)
>   /controlpanel (Laravel)

I want to use the Laravel functionality within the main PHP project.
For example I want to be able to query the database of the control panel with Eloquent models from within **/index.php**.
Something like limited Laravel (without routers, etc).

I have tried to include the **bootstrap/autoload.php** and call Eloquent model, but the IoC Container is not instantiated and it's not working.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of Laravel's packages outside the framework, however it takes some doing in most cases.

> [Laravel Illuminate Router Package In Your Application](http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-illuminate-router-package-in-your-application/)
>
> [Use Eloquent Outside of Laravel](https://laracasts.com/lessons/how-to-use-eloquent-outside-of-laravel)

The resources above are for Laravel 4, but you could use them as a starting point as they might be very similar to the approach needed for Laravel 5 packages.